# Running for loop periodically

Tags: android, loops, delay

I want to run a for loop every 5 minutes for an Android application. Is there a better method than this where less processing is done

```java
for(;;) {
    // code
    final long NANOSEC_PER_SEC = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) < 5 * 60 * NANOSEC_PER_SEC) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `sleep` - not sure of the programming language you are using

Comment: This looks like Java. Is it?

Comment: please share the programming language you're using.

Comment: use an alarm manager
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

`CountDownTimer` is a good class for this kind of work. It looks like this:

```
long duration = 12345;
long ticksInterval = 5000; // 5 second in millis

new CountDownTimer(duration, ticksInterval){
    public void onTick(long remaining) {
        // Do something each ticksInterval millis
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // Do something after duration millis
    }
}.start();
```

That said, I don't think you can use this for an infinite amount of time since it requires an ending time. Though you can hack to restart it once it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for set Repeat Alert for every 5 Minute and Run your code inside that .

Also you can go for use of Handler like below code .

```
final  int REPEAT_CALL=2;

    final int mFIVE_MINUTE=5*60*1000;

    private Handler mHandler=new Handler(){


        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch(msg.what){

                case REPEAT_CALL:
//This will get execute by every 5 minute so write you for loop code here.

                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(REPEAT_CALL,mFIVE_MINUTE);

                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

You can start it by calling this :

```
 mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(REPEAT_CALL,10);
```

Then after it will call by every 5 minute .

You can cancel this call back by calling below method:

```
mHandler.removeMessages(REPEAT_CALL);
```